# Visual Designer in SPD 2013 is blank

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visio

Just some quick background I have a Windows 7 x64 machine with Office 2007 installed.  I have SharePoint Designer 2013 and Visio Professional 2013 installed as well.  I was hoping to utilize the visual designer mode in SharePoint Designer to create some SharePoint Workflows.  For some reason when I switch to visual designer view its blank and doesn't display anything.  All of the office software including Designer and Viso are 32 bit. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, with reinstallation of SharePoint Designer 2013.

I had same problem on my development environment but not on test environment.

When I tried to open and switching workflow (on dev. env.) from SPD 2013 (installed on test env.) on visual designer, all work fine.

I compared two installations of SPD (dev and test) and I found
on test I've installed only SPD 2013 without updates while
on dev I've SPD and 46 updates.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.**Install SharePoint Designer 2013 & Visio Professional on the same machine**
>
> ◦The Visual Designer will not work in any previous versions of SPD
>
> ◦Only Visio Pro will enable the Visual Designer
>
> 2.**Connect SharePoint Designer 2013 up to a SharePoint 2013 site that has the Workflow Manager setup**
>
> ◦The Visual Designer will not work on 2010 sites
>
> ◦This is because you can’t create SharePoint 2013 workflows on
> SharePoint 2010 sites
>
> ◦You can find more info on how to setup the Workflow Manager here:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj163276(v=office.15)
>
> 3.**Create a new SharePoint 2013 workflow**
>
> ◦The Visual Designer will only work when creating / editing SharePoint
> 2013 workflows
>
> ◦You cannot use this feature to create / edit SharePoint 2010
> workflows

and finally enable like so:

[image]

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/10/22/introducing-the-new-visual-designer.aspx